# Как парсить динамические страницы PHP

Tags: php, парсер, youtube, simple-html-dom, phpquery

**Задание:** Спарсить динамически подгружаемый блок на YouTube *(блок лицензии под описанием с id #collapsible)*.
Начальный DOM страницы состоит из закодированных скриптов, поэтому PHP не видит желаемого элемента.
Лишь после полной отработки JS загружаются все остальные данные.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Уточнение:** YouTube API и oEmbed НЕ подходят для этих нужд

**Подскажите** как решить это посредством PHP (решит ли вопрос phpQuery) или другие способы решения.

**Опыт:** Подключил библиотеку «Simple Html Dom Php», однако она работает только со статическими страницами.

**Код:** Мое решение на котором остановился

```js
<?php
    require 'simple_html_dom.php'; //подключаем библиотеку
    $link = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdmBTTAFlk0';
    $html = file_get_html( $link ); // получаем страницу

    $load = file_get_contents( $link );
    $html= str_get_html( $load );

    echo $element = $html->find('#collapsible', 0);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как решить это посредством PHP

Достаточно сложно, т.к. PHP не слишком предназначен для этого. Один из вариантов - [V8js](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php) модуль.

> другие способы решения

Взять Node.js и [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hc16Y9fiCvQ');

    await page.waitForSelector('paper-button#more');

    await page.click('paper-button#more');

    await page.waitForSelector('#collapsible ytd-metadata-row-header-renderer');

    let desc = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let innerText = [];
        document.querySelectorAll('ytd-metadata-row-renderer.ytd-metadata-row-container-renderer')
            .forEach(node => innerText.push(node.innerText));

        return Promise.resolve(innerText);
    })


    console.log(desc);

    await browser.close();
})();
```

[Есть и для Python](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/), но лично не пробовал.

Comment: Дяка за столь развернутый ответ!
Не буду делать костылей с PHP, лучше перейду на стоящее решение.
По поводу Node.js только что почитал. На нем есть множество решений, вот только не нашел хостинга на нем, a VPS не охота брать.
Так что найду решение с Python. Спасибо! 